# Xamarin c# CSV being created in Android directory but not written to

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, csv, xamarin

I am currently creating a CSV file and trying to write the contents of my SQLite database to it.  Unfortunately I keep getting the "Sharing Violation on path" error.  It errors on the line where I try to WriteAllText.

Below is my current code:

```
var fileName = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "pullList" + pullMonth + ".csv";

using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    //Write your file here
    //fs.WriteLine("Hello");
    foreach (var listing in allTables)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(fileName), string.Format("{0}," + System.Environment.NewLine, listing.ComicTitle));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating a stream, but not using it to write.  Since the stream is creating the file with FileShare.None, when you try to write using a different file handle, it throws the sharing exception

try this instead

```
var filename = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory, "pullList" + pullMonth + ".csv");

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

// build the data in memory
foreach (var listing in allTables)
{
    s = s.AppendLine(listing.ComicTitle);
}

// write the data all at once
File.WriteAllText(path,s);
```

Comment: I tried this and i get "Argument 2 cannot convert from System.Text.StringBuilder to string
 File.WriteAllText(fileName,s);

Comment: Okay i just converted it to a String and it worked! Thank you so much. Something that was this simple took me forever haha.  No violation error and all titles are written in separate lines in CSV.